# What is the formula for how many combinations are there for this?

Tags: combinatorics

So, as the question says how many combinations for a set like $\{a,b,c,d\}$ such that it outputs when we say $k=3$ this:

> $ABC, ACD, ABD$
>
> $BCD$

so there is no repetition **AT ALL**, so we can't have this:

> $BCD$ and $CBD$

?

Comment: Combinatorics: $4\choose{k}$ or if there is $n$ number of letter/terms $n \choose{k}$

Comment: These are called [combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination).  The formula is $$\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n - k)!}$$

Comment: @N.F.Taussig: Could this also be written as $$=\frac{n_n*n_{n-1}*n_{n-2}...n_k}{k!}$$

Comment: Or this:$$\frac{(n)(n-1)(n-2)...(n-k+1)}{k!}$$

Comment: Thanks! Now it is obvious but my head stuck for a second and I needed it right now...

Comment: @AopsVol.2 Yes, $$\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n - k)!} =  \frac{n(n -1)(n - 2) \cdots (n - k + 1)(n - k)!}{k!(n - k)!}= \frac{n(n -1)(n - 2) \cdots (n - k + 1)}{k!}$$

Answer (score 0):

The number of $k$ element subsets of an $n$ element set is given by the [binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) $\binom{n}{k}$, read aloud as "n choose k", which can be shown to equal:

$$\binom{n}{k}=\dfrac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$$